# Embedded ECL lisp error handling

Tags: error-handling, lisp, common-lisp, ecl

Task: Embed ECL lisp in my project, setup error handling and detailed error reporting (where occurred, kind of error, etc.)

I tried to do that such way:

```
cl_def_c_function_va(
    c_string_to_object("SYSTEM:UNIVERSAL-ERROR-HANDLER"),
    LispErrorHandler);
```

ECL have no documentation on its embedded API and no documentation on error handling...

Can you suggest how to implement that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no global error handler because this is not the Common Lisp philosophy. If you want to handle errors, do it the lisp way.

1) Create a function that uses HANDLER-CASE or HANDLER-BIND to set up the appropriate error handlers and catch errors around a form that is to be evaluated. Something like

(DEFUN MY-EVAL (FORM)
  (HANDLER-CASE (EVAL FORM)
     (ERROR (C) ...)
     (MY-ERROR (C) ...)
     ...))

This function may be defined in your C code and invoked.

2) Use the functions that ECL creates that catch all errors. The most important one is si_safe_eval(form, environment, error_value). It evaluates the lisp FORM in an ENVIRONMENT (Typically Cnil) and returns its output or ERROR_VALUE if it got some error.

Some examples that use one or the other technique:
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.ecl.general/5365 (2nd message)
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.ecl.general/8526/focus=8529

Comment: ...But try to evaluate `(defun SYSTEM:UNIVERSAL-ERROR-HANDLER (a1 a2 a3) t)` and then `(qwertyuiop)`, error message implied that function exists (1) and can be coded/altered (2).

You sure, that we can`t use that?

It is not a 'tedium', but 'scientific' interest, you may not answer, if you don`t want ;) Thanks again!

Comment: system:universal-error-handler is not to be messed with, please. If you want to change error handler, use the Common Lisp standard. This function exists only for internal purposes and you are trying to guess that it can be overriden when it cannot. It is used internally by Common Lisp's SIGNAL in a way which is not to be exposed to the user. Intercepting it does not make errors just go away -- proper handling of errors is expected everywhere in ECL. What happens if you override that function and then evaluate (SIN "Hello") ?